# Encryption for android. How to do that?

Tags: android, encryption

When i download 'app' from play store and try to see code in it, all I can see is null null null..... . If I have to achieve that kind of encryption how can I do that. From where should I start. What should I start searching in internet. I want to encrypt entire application.

Comment: How are you attempting to see the code? If an app can be run, it can be decompiled.

Comment: it is not clear where you see that nulls

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko when decompile the apk some secured apps code not able to read. Java classes not have full of code it contains null something

Comment: you probably have decompiled it incorrectly then. Java classes can always be decompiled into source code. What you can do at most is th obfuscate the code

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko for instance I download paytm or swigy app and if I try to see code in .xml file all I can see is null null null.

Comment: which xml are you trying? You have to decode the xml resources

Answer (score 1):

You need to obfuscate your code using Proguard. It not just obfuscates the code but also shrinks and optimizes it. You can read in detail about it at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code

Comment: obfuscating code does not result in "only null null null"

Comment: You're right. From the question, I inferred he wants to obfuscate his code. The apk might not be decompiled properly.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question . Its is answer to how to obfuscate . Only guess i can make here is apk might not be decompiled properly .